# Shouldn't an undefined variable throw an exception on checking with #if?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    #if (!pi)
                Console.WriteLine("i");
    #else 
                Console.WriteLine("PI undefined");
    #endif
        Console.WriteLine("ok");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> i 
>  
>   ok

Can anybody explain to me how? If `pi` is not defined, shouldn't it throw an exception?

Comment: Which variable is undefined here?

Comment: #if (!pi)    synonymous  with C++ syntax of   #ifndef pi    --- which if the term is not defined, include during compilation

Comment: `pi` is not a *variable*, it is a *symbol*. Symbols doesn't have a value, they're either defined or they're not.

Comment: You might want to [read some documentation about `#if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if).

Comment: not sure why anyone down ticked the question... seems like a valid question to me

Comment: I give up. What's your error?

Comment: downvoter please care to mention reason.

Comment: An exception is a *runtime*-thing, whereas a preprocessor-directive is evaluated at compile-time. Thus only the appropriate branch is baked into the assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#If` directive specifically checks whether the given symbol is defined or not.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if):

> When the C# compiler encounters an `#if` directive, followed
>   eventually by an #endif directive, it compiles the code between the
>   directives **only if the specified symbol is defined**. Unlike C and C++,
>   you cannot assign a numeric value to a symbol. The #if statement in C#
>   is Boolean and only tests **whether the symbol has been defined or not**.

Furthermore:

> `#define` lets you define a symbol. By then using the symbol as the expression passed to the `#if` directive, the expression evaluates to
>   true.

Therefore, if the symbol (`pi` in your case) hasn't been defined, the result is always false.

Answer (score 3):

The #if condition is a preprocessor directive.

The code between your condition is only compiled, if your condition is defined - or in your case, if `pi` is not defined `#if !pi`.

See the microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confues about what a pre-processor directive is. As the name already suggests it´s something that the compiler evaluates. Thus which of the two branches is baked into the assembly is determined at **comile**-time. This means that only one of them exists in the assembly, the other is ommited at compile-time, see the following IL for the case that `pi` is not defined:

```
 .method public hidebysig static void 
    Main(
      string[] args
    ) cil managed 
  {
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8

    // [15 3 - 15 4]
    IL_0000: nop          

    // [17 4 - 17 27]
    IL_0001: ldstr        "i"
    IL_0006: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000b: nop          

    // [21 4 - 21 28]
    IL_000c: ldstr        "ok"
    IL_0011: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0016: nop          

    // [22 4 - 22 23]
    IL_0017: call         string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
    IL_001c: pop          

    // [23 3 - 23 4]
    IL_001d: ret          

  }
```

When `pi` is defined the IL looks slightly different:

```
.method public hidebysig static void 
    Main(
      string[] args
    ) cil managed 
  {
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8

    // [15 3 - 15 4]
    IL_0000: nop          

    // [19 17 - 19 51]
    IL_0001: ldstr        "PI undefined"
    IL_0006: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000b: nop          

    // [21 4 - 21 28]
    IL_000c: ldstr        "ok"
    IL_0011: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0016: nop          

    // [22 4 - 22 23]
    IL_0017: call         string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
    IL_001c: pop          

    // [23 3 - 23 4]
    IL_001d: ret          

  }
```

As you can see the compiled assembly differs depending if the symbol was defined or not.

So *effectivly* your source-code will look similar to this if `pi` is defined (see first IL-code)

```
Console.WriteLine("i");
Console.WriteLine("ok");
Console.ReadLine();
```

and (see second IL-code)

```
Console.WriteLine("PI undefined");
Console.WriteLine("ok");
Console.ReadLine();
```

if it is not defined.

As you see there´s no way the code could cause an exception that `pi` is undefined, as `pi` doesn´t exist in the compiled assembly at all.